# Project Base Localization not english

Tags: ios, localization, appstore-approval

I have this project that will be published in a **non-english** speaking region at the star, and maybe if the app works we will later publish it in another regions

To easier the development the base localization of the project is at the current region language, which is **not english** and we have the localizables for english in a second localizable files.

So will the base localization bring some problems in the appstore approval if it is not english?

Comment: Not at all.  I have published danish only app with no issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)